# Visual Studio Code Map Error: Could not allocate a new page for database 'Microsoft.VsCodeIndex'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-map

While mapping my source code using the Visual Studio Code Map it index all the code, but after some minutes I get the message:

- MyAssembly.dll: Assembly cannot be loaded: C:\PathToMySolution\PathToMyProject\bin\MyProject.dll Could not allocate a new page for database 'Microsoft.VsCodeIndex' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

Each time I try I get the same error message, but the assembly changes to another. The print below show one of my cases:

[image: Visual Studio Code Map Error: Could not allocate a new page for database 'Microsoft.VsCodeIndex'...]

If I click on "Open the XML Editor" nothing happens and if I try copy the message to clipboard is copied this message:

```
<DirectedGraph DataVirtualized="True" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml">
  <Nodes>
    <Node Id="(@1 @2 @3 Member=(Name=ProcessarBaseDeContribuicaoPorParticipante OverloadingParameters=[@7,@10,@11,@12,@13,@15,@7,@16,@17,@18]))" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <Node Id="(@1 @2 @3 Member=(Name=ProcessarCalculoDeContribuicaoPorParticipante OverloadingParameters=[@7,@10,@11,@11,@12,@13,@15,(@5 @6 Type=(Name=Action GenericParameterCount=2 GenericArguments=[(@8 Namespace=CM.CMPrevWeb.ContribuicaoPrev.Domain Type=HistoricoContribuicao),(@5 Namespace=System.Collections.Generic Type=(Name=IEnumerable GenericParameterCount=1 GenericArguments=[(@8 @9 Type=OpcaoPorContribuicaoDoParticipante)]))])),@7,@7,@7,@19,@7,@16,@13,@19,@7,@17,@20,(@5 Namespace=System.Collections.Generic Type=(Name=List GenericParameterCount=1 GenericArguments=[@20])),@19,@18,@7,@7]))" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <Node Id="(@1 @2 @3 Member=(Name=ProcessarRecalculoDeContribuicaoPorParticipante OverloadingParameters=[@7,@10,@11,@11,@12,@13,@15,(@5 @6 Type=(Name=Action GenericParameterCount=2 GenericArguments=[(@8 Namespace=CM.CMPrevWeb.ContribuicaoPrev.Domain Type=HistoricoContribuicao),(@5 Namespace=System.Collections.Generic Type=(Name=IEnumerable GenericParameterCount=1 GenericArguments=[(@8 @9 Type=OpcaoPorContribuicaoDoParticipante)]))])),@7,@7,@7,@19,@7,@16,@13,@19,@7,@17,@20,(@5 Namespace=System.Collections.Generic Type=(Name=List GenericParameterCount=1 GenericArguments=[@20])),@19,@18]))" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <Node Id="@21" Category="CodeSchema_Method" Bounds="245.639617141374,344.138240708159,287.226666666667,25.96" CodeSchemaProperty_IsPrivate="True" CommonLabel="ProcessarCalculoDeContribuicaoPorParticipante" IsDragSource="True" Label="ProcessarCalculoDeContribuicaoPorParticipante" />
    <Node Id="@4" Visibility="Hidden" />
  </Nodes>
  <Links>
    <Link Source="(@1 @2 @3 Member=(Name=ProcessarBaseDeContribuicaoPorParticipante OverloadingParameters=[@7,@10,@11,@12,@13,@15,@7,@16,@17,@18]))" Target="@21" Bounds="271.881336618329,314.138240708159,73.4740818749177,26.9052791831603" />
    <Link Source="(@1 @2 @3 Member=(Name=ProcessarCalculoDeContribuicaoPorParticipante OverloadingParameters=[@7,@10,@11,@11,@12,@13,@15,(@5 @6 Type=(Name=Action GenericParameterCount=2 GenericArguments=[(@8 Namespace=CM.CMPrevWeb.ContribuicaoPrev.Domain Type=HistoricoContribuicao),(@5 Namespace=System.Collections.Generic Type=(Name=IEnumerable GenericParameterCount=1 GenericArguments=[(@8 @9 Type=OpcaoPorContribuicaoDoParticipante)]))])),@7,@7,@7,@19,@7,@16,@13,@19,@7,@17,@20,(@5 Namespace=System.Collections.Generic Type=(Name=List GenericParameterCount=1 GenericArguments=[@20])),@19,@18,@7,@7]))" Target="@21" Bounds="434.2017616038,314.138240708159,75.8118420743332,26.9822403731616" />
    <Link Source="(@1 @2 @3 Member=(Name=ProcessarRecalculoDeContribuicaoPorParticipante OverloadingParameters=[@7,@10,@11,@11,@12,@13,@15,(@5 @6 Type=(Name=Action GenericParameterCount=2 GenericArguments=[(@8 Namespace=CM.CMPrevWeb.ContribuicaoPrev.Domain Type=HistoricoContribuicao),(@5 Namespace=System.Collections.Generic Type=(Name=IEnumerable GenericParameterCount=1 GenericArguments=[(@8 @9 Type=OpcaoPorContribuicaoDoParticipante)]))])),@7,@7,@7,@19,@7,@16,@13,@19,@7,@17,@20,(@5 Namespace=System.Collections.Generic Type=(Name=List GenericParameterCount=1 GenericArguments=[@20])),@19,@18]))" Target="@21" Bounds="390.264307080679,225.96,5.02618810087512,109.187761049876" />
    <Link Source="@4" Target="@21" Category="Contains" FetchingParent="@4" />
  </Links>
  <Categories>
    <Category Id="CodeSchema_Member" Label="Member" CanBeDataDriven="True" DefaultAction="Microsoft.Contains" Icon="CodeSchema_Field" NavigationActionLabel="Members" />
    <Category Id="CodeSchema_Method" Label="Method" BasedOn="CodeSchema_Member" CanBeDataDriven="True" DefaultAction="Link:Forward:CodeSchema_Calls" Icon="CodeSchema_Method" NavigationActionLabel="Methods" />
    <Category Id="Contains" Label="Contains" Description="Whether the source of the link contains the target object" CanBeDataDriven="False" CanLinkedNodesBeDataDriven="True" IncomingActionLabel="Contained By" IsContainment="True" OutgoingActionLabel="Contains" />
  </Categories>
  <Properties>
    <Property Id="Bounds" DataType="System.Windows.Rect" />
    <Property Id="CanBeDataDriven" Label="CanBeDataDriven" Description="CanBeDataDriven" DataType="System.Boolean" />
    <Property Id="CanLinkedNodesBeDataDriven" Label="CanLinkedNodesBeDataDriven" Description="CanLinkedNodesBeDataDriven" DataType="System.Boolean" />
    <Property Id="CodeSchemaProperty_IsPrivate" Label="Is Private" Description="Flag to indicate the scope is Private" DataType="System.Boolean" />
    <Property Id="CommonLabel" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="DataVirtualized" Label="Data Virtualized" Description="If true, the graph can contain nodes and links that represent data for virtualized nodes/links (i.e. not actually created in the graph)." DataType="System.Boolean" />
    <Property Id="DefaultAction" Label="DefaultAction" Description="DefaultAction" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="Expression" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="FetchingParent" DataType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphModel.GraphNodeId" />
    <Property Id="GroupLabel" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="Icon" Label="Icon" Description="Icon" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="IncomingActionLabel" Label="IncomingActionLabel" Description="IncomingActionLabel" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="IsContainment" DataType="System.Boolean" />
    <Property Id="IsDragSource" Label="IsDragSource" Description="IsDragSource" DataType="System.Boolean" />
    <Property Id="IsEnabled" DataType="System.Boolean" />
    <Property Id="Label" Label="Label" Description="Displayable label of an Annotatable object" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="NavigationActionLabel" Label="NavigationActionLabel" Description="NavigationActionLabel" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="OutgoingActionLabel" Label="OutgoingActionLabel" Description="OutgoingActionLabel" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="TargetType" DataType="System.Type" />
    <Property Id="Value" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="ValueLabel" DataType="System.String" />
    <Property Id="Visibility" Label="Visibility" Description="Defines whether a node in the graph is visible or not" DataType="System.Windows.Visibility" />
  </Properties>
  <QualifiedNames>
    <Name Id="Assembly" Label="Assembly" ValueType="Uri" />
    <Name Id="GenericArguments" Label="Generic Arguments" ValueType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphModel.GraphNodeIdCollection" />
    <Name Id="GenericParameterCount" Label="Generic Parameter Count" ValueType="System.String" />
    <Name Id="Member" Label="Member" ValueType="System.Object" />
    <Name Id="Name" Label="Name" ValueType="System.String" />
    <Name Id="Namespace" Label="Namespace" ValueType="System.String" />
    <Name Id="OverloadingParameters" Label="Parameter" ValueType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphModel.GraphNodeIdCollection" Formatter="NameValueNoEscape" />
    <Name Id="ParamKind" Label="Parameter Kind" ValueType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphModel.CodeSchema.ParamKind" />
    <Name Id="Type" Label="Type" ValueType="System.Object" />
  </QualifiedNames>
  <IdentifierAliases>
    <Alias n="1" Uri="Assembly=$(fcf5c60f-6a11-4ad4-bb66-72193ed0fae9.OutputPathUri)" />
    <Alias n="2" Id="Namespace=CM.CMPrevWeb.ContribuicaoPrev.Service" />
    <Alias n="3" Id="Type=CalcularContribuicaoService" />
    <Alias n="4" Id="(@1 @2 @3)" />
    <Alias n="5" Uri="Assembly=$(ProgramFilesUri) (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/.NETFramework/v4.8/mscorlib.dll" />
    <Alias n="6" Id="Namespace=System" />
    <Alias n="7" Id="(@5 @6 Type=Boolean)" />
    <Alias n="8" Uri="Assembly=$(8d4b3d9c-bdfd-47d5-bacc-f11f6863879d.OutputPathUri)" />
    <Alias n="9" Id="Namespace=CM.CMPrevWeb.CadastroPrev.Domain" />
    <Alias n="10" Id="(@8 @9 Type=ParticipantePorPlano)" />
    <Alias n="11" Id="(@8 Namespace=CM.CMPrevWeb.CorePrev.Domain Type=AnoMesDeReferencia)" />
    <Alias n="12" Id="(@8 Namespace=CM.CMPrevWeb.ParamPrev.Domain Type=MotivoPorParametroParamPrev)" />
    <Alias n="13" Id="(@5 @6 Type=Int32)" />
    <Alias n="14" Uri="Assembly=$(0ea13118-a0d0-4e7d-98c3-da206ecc7ecf.OutputPathUri)" />
    <Alias n="15" Id="(@14 Namespace=CM.CMFlex.Core.Domain.Common Type=SistemaEnum)" />
    <Alias n="16" Id="(@5 @6 Type=Decimal)" />
    <Alias n="17" Id="(@8 @9 Type=EventoPorParticipante)" />
    <Alias n="18" Id="(@8 Namespace=CM.CMPrevWeb.CorePrev.Domain Type=ProcessoDeOrigemParaRegraEnum)" />
    <Alias n="19" Id="(@5 @6 Type=(Name=Nullable GenericParameterCount=1 GenericArguments=[(@5 @6 Type=DateTime)]))" />
    <Alias n="20" Id="(@8 @9 Type=BeneficioPorBeneficiario)" />
    <Alias n="21" Id="(@1 @2 @3 Member=(Name=ProcessarCalculoDeContribuicaoPorParticipante OverloadingParameters=[@10,@11,@11,@12,(@8 @9 Type=ContribuicaoPorParticipante ParamKind=Ref),@13,(@8 Namespace=CM.CMPrevWeb.ContribuicaoPrev.Domain Type=HistoricoContribuicao ParamKind=Ref),@15,@7,@7,@7,@7,@16,@13,@19,@7,@17,@20,(@5 Namespace=System.Collections.Generic Type=(Name=List GenericParameterCount=1 GenericArguments=[@20])),@19,@18,@7,@7]))" />
  </IdentifierAliases>
  <Styles>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Results" ValueLabel="True">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('QueryResult')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFBCFFBE" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Test Project" ValueLabel="Test Project">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeMap_TestProject')" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeMap_TestProject" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF307A69" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Web Project" ValueLabel="Web Project">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeMap_WebProject')" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeMap_WebProject" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Windows Store Project" ValueLabel="Windows Store Project">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeMap_WindowsStoreProject')" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeMap_WindowsStoreProject" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Phone Project" ValueLabel="Phone Project">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeMap_PhoneProject')" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeMap_PhoneProject" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Portable Library" ValueLabel="Portable Library">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeMap_PortableLibraryProject')" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeMap_PortableLibraryProject" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="WPF Project" ValueLabel="WPF Project">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeMap_WpfProject')" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeMap_WpfProject" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="VSIX Project" ValueLabel="VSIX Project">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeMap_VsixProject')" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeMap_VsixProject" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Modeling Project" ValueLabel="Modeling Project">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeMap_ModelingProject')" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeMap_ModelingProject" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Assembly" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_Assembly')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF094167" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF094167" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_Assembly" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Namespace" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_Namespace')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0E619A" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF0E619A" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_Namespace" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Interface" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_Interface')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1382CE" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF1382CE" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_Interface" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Struct" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_Struct')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1382CE" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF1382CE" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_Struct" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Enumeration" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_Enum')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1382CE" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF1382CE" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_Enum" />
      <Setter Property="LayoutSettings" Value="List" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Delegate" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_Delegate')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1382CE" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF1382CE" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_Delegate" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Class" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_Type')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0E70C0" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF0E70C0" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_Class" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Property" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_Property')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE0E0E0" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FFE0E0E0" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_Property" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Method" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_Method') Or HasCategory('CodeSchema_CallStackUnresolvedMethod')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE0E0E0" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FFE0E0E0" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_Method" />
      <Setter Property="LayoutSettings" Value="List" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Event" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_Event')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE0E0E0" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FFE0E0E0" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_Event" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Field" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_Field')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE0E0E0" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FFE0E0E0" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_Field" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Out Parameter" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="CodeSchemaProperty_IsOut = 'True'" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_OutParameter" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Parameter" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_Parameter')" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_Parameter" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Local Variable" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_LocalExpression')" />
      <Setter Property="Icon" Value="CodeSchema_LocalExpression" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Externals" ValueLabel="Has category">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('Externals')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF424242" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF424242" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="Inherits From" ValueLabel="True">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('InheritsFrom')" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF00A600" />
      <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="2 0" />
      <Setter Property="DrawArrow" Value="true" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="Implements" ValueLabel="True">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('Implements')" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#8000A600" />
      <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="2 2" />
      <Setter Property="DrawArrow" Value="true" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="Calls" ValueLabel="True">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_Calls')" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FFFF00FF" />
      <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="2 0" />
      <Setter Property="DrawArrow" Value="true" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="Function Pointer" ValueLabel="True">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_FunctionPointer')" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FFFF00FF" />
      <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="2 2" />
      <Setter Property="DrawArrow" Value="true" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="Field Read" ValueLabel="True">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_FieldRead')" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF00AEEF" />
      <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="2 2" />
      <Setter Property="DrawArrow" Value="true" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="Field Write" ValueLabel="True">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_FieldWrite')" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF00AEEF" />
      <Setter Property="DrawArrow" Value="true" />
      <Setter Property="IsHidden" Value="false" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="Inherits From" ValueLabel="True" Visibility="Hidden">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('InheritsFrom') And Target.HasCategory('CodeSchema_Class')" />
      <Setter Property="TargetDecorator" Value="OpenArrow" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="Implements" ValueLabel="True" Visibility="Hidden">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('Implements') And Target.HasCategory('CodeSchema_Interface')" />
      <Setter Property="TargetDecorator" Value="OpenArrow" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="Comment Link" ValueLabel="True" Visibility="Hidden">
      <Condition Expression="Source.HasCategory('Comment')" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FFE5C365" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Cursor Location Changed" ValueLabel="True" Visibility="Hidden">
      <Condition Expression="IsCursorLocation" />
      <Setter Property="IndicatorWest" Value="WestIndicator" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Disabled Breakpoint Location Changed" ValueLabel="True" Visibility="Hidden">
      <Condition Expression="DisabledBreakpointCount" />
      <Setter Property="IndicatorWest" Value="WestIndicator" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Enabled Breakpoint Location Changed" ValueLabel="True" Visibility="Hidden">
      <Condition Expression="EnabledBreakpointCount" />
      <Setter Property="IndicatorWest" Value="WestIndicator" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Instruction Pointer Location Changed" ValueLabel="True" Visibility="Hidden">
      <Condition Expression="IsInstructionPointerLocation" />
      <Setter Property="IndicatorWest" Value="WestIndicator" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Current Callstack Changed" ValueLabel="True" Visibility="Hidden">
      <Condition Expression="IsCurrentCallstackFrame" />
      <Setter Property="IndicatorWest" Value="WestIndicator" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="Return" ValueLabel="True" Visibility="Hidden">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_ReturnTypeLink')" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="References" ValueLabel="True" Visibility="Hidden">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('References')" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="Uses Attribute" ValueLabel="True" Visibility="Hidden">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeSchema_AttributeUse')" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Node" GroupLabel="Solution Folder" ValueLabel="True" Visibility="Hidden">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeMap_SolutionFolder')" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFDEBA83" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="Project Reference" ValueLabel="Project Reference">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeMap_ProjectReference')" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#9A9A9A" />
      <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="2 2" />
      <Setter Property="DrawArrow" Value="true" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Link" GroupLabel="External Reference" ValueLabel="External Reference">
      <Condition Expression="HasCategory('CodeMap_ExternalReference')" />
      <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#9A9A9A" />
      <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="2 2" />
      <Setter Property="DrawArrow" Value="true" />
    </Style>
  </Styles>
  <Paths>
    <Path Id="0ea13118-a0d0-4e7d-98c3-da206ecc7ecf.OutputPathUri" Value="file:///F:/src/TST/Out/Core/CM.CMFlex.Core.Domain.dll" />
    <Path Id="8d4b3d9c-bdfd-47d5-bacc-f11f6863879d.OutputPathUri" Value="file:///F:/src/TST/Out/CorePrev/CM.CMPrevWeb.CorePrev.Domain.dll" />
    <Path Id="fcf5c60f-6a11-4ad4-bb66-72193ed0fae9.OutputPathUri" Value="file:///F:/src/TST/Out/ContribuicaoPrev/CM.CMPrevWeb.ContribuicaoPrev.Service.dll" />
    <Path Id="ProgramFilesUri" Value="file:///C:/Program Files" />
  </Paths>
</DirectedGraph>
```

An important information about my project and solution is my solution has more than 300 projects and more than 14 million code lines written, but I can't remove or hide some of my projects because I need to map some members over all my solution and is quite impossible to do it manually.

On smaller solutions I don't have this problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

This MS page shows more about the Visual Studio Code Map:

- [Map dependencies with code maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2022)

I already searched about this error, but there is no results with exactly these terms on Google Search, but most of I found is about SQL Server during the management of DataBases, which is not my case.

If the Visual Studio is creating an DB to index my code, maybe is possible to me do the suggestions of the error message, but I don't know where is localizated this DB and if it's accessible.

Comment: You can go to [Visual Studio for feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home).)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Microsoft.VsCodeIndex_???.mdf database responsible for this error at `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Temp\VS11CodeIndex`.
You could try some maintenance on this like set the database autogrow so it can expand automatically.
In my case the easy way that I found to bypass this is to open the **(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB** and remove records from some tables

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [System.Runtime].[CalledMethodsTable]
TRUNCATE TABLE [ArchitectureTools.Runtime].[AssemblyDependenciesTable]
```

Now you can go back to codemap and try again